# System Verilog always_latch vs. always_ff

Tags: system-verilog, vlsi, register-transfer-level

I am confused about the usage of statements `always_ff` and `always_latch`.
The former would be used as:

```
always_ff @ (posedge clk)
begin
    a <= b;
end
```

while the latter:

```
always_latch
begin
    a <= b;
end
```

The first is activated just by the positive edge of the clock and, coupled with nonblocking assignment, produces a FF.

The `always_latch` is obviously thought to represent a latch, but then why use a nonblocking assignment?

Wouldn't it be better using an `always_comb` with blocking assignments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using always_latch or always_ff a designers intent to infer a latch or a sequential logic respectively, but if the logic is not correct software tools can warn the designer that the intended hardware logic is not inferred properly.

eg:

```
always_ff @ (posedge clk or negedge rst) 
begin
  if (!rst)
    a <= '0;
end
```

For the above code the designer intended to get only a sequential logic and not a latch but a latch would be generated in actual (Any static tool will generate a warning message as "Latch will be inferred for the logic")

Similarly for the below code the designers intent is to infer a hardware latch so tool will(understand your logic better) and won't report it.

```
    always_latch
    begin
      if (rst)
        a <= b;
    end
```

Latch is a sequential logic which works on levels of clocks instead of clock edges.

In general best practice is to use Non-blocking assignments for sequential logic and blocking assignments for combinatorial logic which is explained in detail under Section 5.0
Verilog coding guidelines of [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)

> Guideline #2: When modeling latches, use nonblocking assignments.

Answer (score 3):

From IEEE Std 1800-2012, section "9.2.2.3 Latched logic always_latch procedure":

> The always_latch construct is identical to the always_comb construct
> except that software tools should perform additional checks and warn
> if the behavior in an always_latch construct does not represent
> latched logic, whereas in an always_comb construct, tools should check
> and warn if the behavior does not represent combinational logic.

The code example in the Std shows the always_latch using a non-blocking assignment.